# Show/Hide Field Based on Any Value in a Dropdown in PowerApps

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-forms

I get how to hide/show a dropdown based on multiple/different individual values of another dropdown, but is there a way to code the dropdown to show if any value is selected rather than specifying each possible option?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick in the Visible property of the field you want to hide/show:

```
If(!IsBlank(Datacardvalue24.Selected.Value), true, false)
```

So this formular will check if datacard24 selected value is empty or not, and assign true/false to the visibility accordingly.